# stsadm differential backups when directories are renamed?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, backup, stsadm

currently I have a full backup running daily in SharePoint.  The automated process for further copying, renames the full backup directory to backup_((date in yyyymmdd))_full.  I'd like to rework to a daily incremental/weekly full schedule, but the differentials can't seem to find the last full backup to work with.  I was thinking of further extending the batch jobs to record the SharePoint name and do a quick rename before the differential executes, but does anyone have an easier way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why differentials aren't working is because SharePoint cannot find the spbrtoc.xml file. This file records a history of the backups taken and is updated whenever you perform a backup. Renaming the backup directory is preventing SharePoint from finding this file, so it can't work out how to perform a differential.

I would strongly recommend searching the web for SharePoint backup scripts as many others have been down this path and you should be able to adapt what they've done. Here are a few links I found:

- [SharePoint Backup with Powershell](http://www.codeplex.com/spbackup)
- [SharePoint Backup with VBScript](http://www.blogaboutsharepoint.com/?p=268)

The Technet articles under [Back up and restore the farm](http://www.blogaboutsharepoint.com/?p=268) might also be helpful. Good luck!